# Android Display content through the Video-out

Tags: android, video

Does Android have the software capabilities to, if a phone has video-out, to open or push content solely to the video out.

So for example if the user is in and clicks on a YouTube link, the app, instead of opening the content on the main screen over the app it would push it to the video out so the YouTube video would display on their connect display and they could continue to browse.

I know Motorola's have the `WebTop` software and this idea is similar to what I am trying to accomplish but on a much more basic level. It's more similar to Apples AirPlay but much less complex again (without a network/external player - just video out).

Or if even that is to complex an even simpler solution of having the video-out still output even when the phone is locked. Currently the video-out mirroring on both my HTC Incredible and Galaxy Nexus will stop when the phone is locked.

EDIT:

I've noticed while using my phone that playing a video through the `Google Videos` app that on the phone controls will overlay on the screen i.e. play, pause, seek bar, and, the soft buttons, but the video-out display (Television) plays the video continuously/seamlessly without any of the controls over-layed. Now this is very primitive example of what i'm ultimately alluding too but it does show a real world example of an android device (no 3rd party manufacture software) doing video out that isn't exactly mirroring.

Comment: I know this is possible with AIR for android... so it must be possible in native Android... curious what people will recommend.

Comment: I've been messing around with that but haven't found anything real promising. I did post on the AdobeAir dev site and am awaiting reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... I hate to furnish this as an answer, but it really looks like there's simply nothing in the API for it at all...

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9e3bcd1eea2c379

which just redirects to:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/Jxp_9ZtzL60

I'm definitely going to favorite this question, and hope someone chimes in with something more useful than a "doesn't look like it's possible, though that does appear to be the correct answer, at this time.

Comment: I've been searching for the past week and have come to the same conclusion. One would think that the Bluetooth HID support with ICS would lead to dual-display software becoming more popular.

Answer (score 0):

Much like Dr.Dredel has mentioned, there is nothing current for multiple displays in terms of display 1 showing 'A' and display 2 showing 'B'

There is support for multiple screen sizes per the following:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

This will be the case for a little while longer until someone creates the support for it.